# BigInteger to byte[] without twos complement?

Tags: java

I have a digital signature (`byte[] signedBytes`) in `byte[] array`. I need to convert this to `BigInteger` (`bigSignedBytes`), use the resulting number for something, and then convert back to `byte[] convertBackSignedBytes` from the `BigInteger`.

```
byte[] signedBytes = rsa.sign();
BigInteger bigSigned = new BigInteger(signedBytes);
convertBackSignedBytes = bigSigned.toByteArray();
//signedBytes and convertBackSignedBytes differ.
```

Problem is after the reconversion from `BigInteger` back to `byte[] convertBackSignedBytes` - it appears it differs from my original `signedBytes` variable. I know `BigInteger.toByteArray()` returns a twos complement `byte[] value` - which could be responsible.

So how do I get original bytes from `BigInteger` without the twos complement?

Somebody recommended this:

```
byte[] convertBackSignedBytes = bigIntegerValue.toByteArray();
if (convertBackSignedBytes[0] == 0) {
    byte[] tmp = new byte[convertBackSignedBytes.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(convertBackSignedBytes, 1, tmp, 0, tmp.length);
    convertBackSignedBytes = tmp;
}
```

Tried it - didn't work. Still returns different byte[]value from original `signedBytes`.

If I try to verify the original signature - it succeeds.

But if I try to verify using the converted signature - it fails. So `signedBytes` and `convertBackSignedBytes` are no longer the same.

Any quick pointers please?

Comment: I assume it's impossible for you to just retain a copy of the signature as a byte array and avoid the conversion back?

Comment: If you don't change the `BigInteger`, why do you have to convert it back? Don't you still have a reference to the original `byte[]`? If you change the `BigInteger`, then it's clear why the bytes also change.

Comment: There is no other well defined binary format for negative numbers. Which result would you expect, for instance, for `-1000`?

Comment: @Duncan - there is a valid reason for the conversion. Like I mentioned the BigInteger value is used for something (in the case it is used for encoding the decimal value returned to Base 26 - that cant be done with the original byte[] array or can it?)

Comment: @DeepCoder I'm not disputing the validity of converting the byte array to a BigInteger. However, you may not need to covert the BigInteger back again - just store your original byte array somewhere and re-use it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem. You haven't answered my first question, but here's another one. Is the length of your original `byte[]` always the same, or does it differ from case to case?

Comment: @Duncan - like I stated the requirements of the application make it impossible to store the original byte array and reuse it. The signature verification occurs in a different computer system - and the orignal byte array is not accessible from there, not in the same source code file. I have edited the question, hopefully you would understand what I meant. I think there should be @ least a little focus on answering the original question.

Comment: @DeepCoder That wasn't clear from your original question. We are just trying to help you here.

Comment: @Arian - thanks for your answer. I am sure that if I can get a pointer how to convert a byte[] array from twos complement form (which is what BigInteger returns) to the original unsigned byte[]  - then I should be in business.

Comment: This is nonsense, @DeepCoder: if you do not have access to the byte array, you'll never be able to initialize a BigInteger with it. But if you *do* have access, you can as well save a copy.

Comment: @ jlordo - thanks very much for your reply. I can safely say - the original byte[] length would be the same, say 42 bytes - since the signature is always of the same length. Interestingly - I also notice that even the size of convertBackSignedBytes[] is the same as signedBytes[], in fact Arrays.equals(convertBackSignedBytes, signedBytes) - actually returns true. However "someho" the byte[] arrays are different. With regards to your first question - I don't change the BigInteger in any way. It's the same value that I try to convert back to byte[]. Hope this helps. Again, thanks.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. `Arrays.equals()` returns true for me also. This means the arrays *are* equal. Something else must be at fault. If you are getting the wrong results elsewhere it is due to your methods, not the byte array data.

Comment: @Ingo - I do have access to the original byte array (signedBytes[]) in the source file where I create the BigInteger. That BigInteger is then encoded to Base26 and transmitted to a completely different system where it is required to decode from Base 26 to original BigInteger - and then reconvert back to byte[] - hence the problem. This doesnt sound like nonsense to me. I obviously wouldnt spend all this time - if I could save a copy of the original byte array. You are forgiven for your remarks.

Comment: @DeepCoder: how do you know the byte arrays are different, if `Arrays.equals()` returns `true` ??

Comment: @Duncan - perhaps you do have a point. If Arrays.equals() returns true - then both arrays should be equals, however printing out signedBytes and convertBackSignedBytes (using System.out.println) - prints out different values (it is a known fact that BigInteger.toByteArray() does return a twos complement byte array) - which would be different if the input byte was unsigned). jlordo also mentioned he had been able to repoduce my problem.

Comment: @DuncanJones: reproduce it like this: `byte[] original = {-1, -2}; BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(original); byte[] converted = bi.toByteArray(); Arrays.equals(original, converted); // false` For an explanation of that behavior, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the two's complement should indeed be the problem (I am not convinced) you should be able to solve it by always prepending a 0x00 byte before the original byte array. This way, you'll always have a positive number.

But this, for example could be the problem: if your original array starts with 0x00 or 0xFF bytes, some or all of them may vanish in the process of conversion.

Hence, instead of transferring an integer, why don't you simply transfer a string like "0102affe01dead07cafe89babe"? Encoding bytes to hex string and back should be straightforward.

If you **absolutly must** use a big integer, prepend 0x01 before encoding (this will still give a positive number) and remove it after decoding.

Comment: @jlordo - Sorry for asking. Any code snippet example on how to prepend the 0x01 to the original byte array, and remove it after encoding (as proposed by Ingo)? Thanks again.

Comment: @jlordo -I understand and will ALWAYS try to provide as much information in my questions to answer them intelligibly. But let's call a spade a spade. "This is nonsense, DeepCoder: if you do not have access to the byte array, you'll never be able to initialize a BigInteger with it. But if you do have access, you can as well save a copy. – Ingo 1 hour ago" - isnt just personal - it's actually  a direct VERBAL insult- just pure interpersonal communication skills. Tell you what - I'll just forget about it and get back to work. Once more thanks all! Won't make any more posts about this.

Comment: @DeepCode - you make another array that is 1 longer than the original one, set the byte at index 0 to 0x01. Then copy the original array 0..length_original-1 to the new array index 1..length_original. BTW, I didn't intend to insult you, but when I think something is nonsense, I do tell it.

Comment: By making a mistake in your judgement, you show that you are human. By making a second remark to justify your mistakes - you show that you are proud. I made a post yesterday explaining the actual use case (I think jlordo deleted some of his replies & the post). Find out from him what the exact scenario was. At the minimum, you owe everybody in this forum an apology - although I imagine the same disposition that made you justify your mistake - would also prevent you from making the apology. And by the way, when I think (and have verified) something is the truth - I do tell it.

Comment: You're a bit thin skinned, @DeepCoder.  Nevertheless, I hope you got some help here.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, @Ingo I did get some help to my problem - sincere thanks to jlordo, Ingo and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

the conversion back may be failing because of the lengths being different.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class So15045472 {
    static void print(byte[] bytes) {
        List<Byte> bs=new ArrayList<Byte>(bytes.length);
        for(byte b:bytes)
            bs.add(b);
        System.out.println(bs);
    }
    static boolean compare(byte[] x,byte[] y) {
        if(x.length!=y.length) {
            System.out.println("unequal lengths");
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            if(x[i]!=y[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    static void check(byte[] bytes) {
        BigInteger x=new BigInteger(bytes);
        System.out.println(x);
        byte[] b=x.toByteArray();
        print(bytes);
        print(b);
        boolean isEqual=compare(bytes,b);
        if(!isEqual)
            System.out.println("compare says "+isEqual);
        else System.out.println("ok");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b1=new byte[]{(byte)0x00,(byte)0xff};
        check(b1);
        byte[] b2=new byte[]{(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff};
        check(b2);
    }
}
```