# BigInteger.toByteArray() returns purposeful leading zeros?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm transforming bigints into binary, radix16 and radix64 encoding and seeing mysterious msb zero paddings. Is this a biginteger problem that I can workaround by stripping zero padding or perhaps doing something else?

My test code:

```
    String s;
    System.out.printf( "%s length %d\n", s = "123456789A", (new BigInteger( s, 16 )).toByteArray().length );
    System.out.printf( "%s length %d\n", s = "F23456789A", (new BigInteger( s, 16 )).toByteArray().length );
```

Produces output:

```
    123456789A length 5
    F23456789A length 6
```

Of which the longer array has zero padding at the front. Upon inspection of BigInteger.toByteArray() I see:

```
public byte[] toByteArray() {
    int byteLen = bitLength()/8 + 1;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteLen];
```

Now, I can find `private int bitLength;`, but I can't quite find where bitLength() is defined to figure out exactly why this class does this - connected to sign extension perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Jon Skeet for your answer. Here's some code I'm using to convert, very likely it can be optimized.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UnsignedBigInteger {

    public static byte[] toUnsignedByteArray(BigInteger value) {
        byte[] signedValue = value.toByteArray();
        if(signedValue[0] != 0x00) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be a psoitive BigInteger");
        }
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(signedValue, 1, signedValue.length);
    }

    public static BigInteger fromUnsignedByteArray(byte[] value) {
        byte[] signedValue = new byte[value.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(value,  0, signedValue, 1, value.length);
        return new BigInteger(signedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: From my discussion with Jon I think you might need to left pad your arg to fromUnsignedByte with a zero byte - otherwise, if the arg has it's high bit set your returned value will be negative. no?

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there now.

Comment: Just adding a note to say that code is not correct. A Java BigInteger has an extra zero byte prepended only if it's a positive value with the highest bit set in its magnitude (not including a sign bit). The inputs in the original post show this clearly. `F23456789A` has the highest bit in the first byte `F2` set, so it needs the extra byte (to contain the sign bit).  `123456789A` doesn't. Similarly `723456789A` doesn't.  But `823456789A` does. This can easily be checked.

Comment: I really don't have any idea why the above code is accepted instead of deleted or fixed after it has been clearly *shown* that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is the [documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--):

> The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, **including at least one sign bit**, which is `(ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8))`.

[`bitLength()` is documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--) as:

> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`, excluding a sign bit.

So in other words, two values with the same *magnitude* will always have the same bit length, regardless of sign. Think of a `BigInteger` as being an unsigned integer and a sign bit - and `toByteArray()` returns all the data from both parts, which is "the number of bits required for the unsigned integer, and one bit for the sign".

Comment: When I toString(10) those numbers I get positive values of 78187493530 and 1040260167834 so it looks more like a bug to me. But no matter, I can live with a bug - I just want to know if it's safe to strip the leading zero.

Comment: @orthopteroid: You're considering those as *decimal* values - try printing the *binary* values instead... after all, you're trying to count bits, not decimal digits. As for whether it's "safe" to strip the leading zero, that depends on what you're going to do with it later.

Comment: To clarify, I really can't accept the non-padding leading zeros that toByteArray returns because my purposes are cross-platform radix conversion. Your comment was helpful though - I can use toString(radix) and I'll get an unpadded bit-string. I'll have to fly with that.

Comment: @orthopteroid: So how are you going to differentiate between negative values and non-negative values? It's easy if the first (or last) bit is *always* the sign bit, whether 0 or 1. If you only ever need to work with non-negative values, you're fine - but otherwise you really need to think about it.

Comment: 78187493530 is 1001000110100010101100111100010011010 and 1040260167834  is 1111001000110100010101100111100010011010. I don't think signedness is the issue here (are both negative?). The issue is unnecessary padding.

Comment: @orthopteroid: Are those the values from `toByteArray()`, or what you've decided the result *should* be? (It would be much easier to talk about this with small numbers, by the way - presumably the same issue holds.) I still don't see what's unnecessary about having a bit for the sign. If you could be clearer about the problem - again, using smaller values which are much easier to talk about - it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I have a workaround, but since you asked... I made a short demo of the problem with BigInteger's toByteArray: https://ideone.com/1xllmd The output looks like: `123456789A length 5
F23456789A length 6
13456789A length 5
F3456789A length 5
1456789A length 4
F456789A length 5
156789A length 4
F56789A length 4
16789A length 3
F6789A length 4
1789A length 3
F789A length 3
189A length 2
F89A length 3
19A length 2
F9A length 2
1A length 1
FA length 2
1 length 1
F length 1` so it seems the problem can happen with 1 byte values as well (ie 1A is 1 byte, but FA is 2 bytes).

Comment: @orthopteroid: Yes, I would expect FA to be two bytes, as there are 9 bits of information - 8 for the magnitide and 1 for the sign. I don't see what the problem is. If everything from 0 to FF were a single byte, how would you represent negative values without losing information?

Comment: ummm... I'm guessing 'FA' needs two bytes because java bytes are signed? I think I read that in a book once...

Comment: @orthopteroid: No, it requires two bytes because it has 8 bits of magnitude (11111010) and 1 bit for the sign (positive). How do you propose to get 9 bits of data into a single byte?

Comment: As I understand it java's byte use two's complement, so there really aren't 8 bits of magnitude.

Comment: @orthopteroid: Just think of the byte as 8 bits of data, however you want to use them. Now think that the representation of BigInteger is a magnitude and a sign (as documented). So you have 9 bits of data, which won't fit into 1 byte. Again - think about what you'd want a BigInteger representing -1 to do if you called toByteArray.

Comment: I think in my original question I was struggling with an issue similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045472/biginteger-to-byte-without-twos-complement - namely that toByteArray() returns a twos complement form of the number I initialized it with. I think my solution is to not use toByteArray() but instead use toString(2). Thanks for the java discussion.